# What material to use for a capacitive sensor?

Tags: capacitive, touch-panel

I'm doing a DIY project that I want to use a capacitive sensor for. I'm having a little plastic box and I want to send a wireless message when someone touches the top of it.

I understand all the electronics involved, but I'm clueless towards what to put under the plastic and how to connect a wire to it.

What should I use?

Comment: Are you making a PC board, or just hand wiring a circuit?

Comment: I'm using one of these: https://arduino-shop.cz/arduino/1047-univerzalni-plosny-spoj-30mm-x-70mm-1434557455.html

Answer (score 3):

There's an Adafruit capacitive touch beginner tutorial [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-capacitive-touch-sensor-breakouts/custom-touch-pads-1) that explains that the larger the surface, the more sensitive your touch pad.  If you take a piece blank copper PC board and solder a wire to it and then connect that wire to your capacitive touch sensor, it should be able to sense through the enclosure.  The key here is that the enclosure must be non-conductive plastic.  You could also use copper foil tape, but that is probably more expensive than a small piece of PC board.  Just make sure that whatever you use is attached to the surface with minimal spacing.

If you made an actual PCB, you could put the sensor in the foil on the back of the board and stick that against the inside of the enclosure.